# Blur Background Img, Overflow Hidden, Align with parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have done some research on this, but none of the answers are helping me with my issue. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mezhau3o/) to show what I have so far.

**Problem:**

- I am having an issue when it comes to over flow, as you can see the
  background image is overflowing the wrapper.
- Next issue, The background image doesn't look to be auto filling to
  the wrappers width. I'm assuming that when the overflow issue is
  fixed that this might not be a problem anymore.
- Lastly, when we can fix everything, is there a way to make the
  wrapper extend to the height of the background image without
  specifically setting the height myself.

Here is my code:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.content:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url(../images/10034277536_1454f4e382_background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
       -moz-filter: blur(3px);
        -ms-filter: blur(3px);
         -o-filter: blur(3px);
}

.content {
  z-index: 0;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
    Hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would be better to create a fiddle or something as your image won't load now and we can't see what's wrong.

Comment: @ChrisG Oh srry, I was thinking about that. Im on it

Comment: Let me know when you're done :). Also, include the fiddle link in your original post. It's much cleaner that way

Comment: @ChrisG Ok all edited into the post

Comment: Replace the background image with an actual image (`<img>`) to address bullet number three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/5mahg3fp/

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
 }

.content:before {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Positioning the element absolutey instead of fixed and relatively to `#content` will fix your first problem.

Setting the `backgrund-size` to `cover` makes the background grow to the size of the element.

To have an element automatically growing to the size of the background assigned you would have to insert the background as an actual image, positioned statically. The you could add your content to a absolutely positioned child that covers the whole area.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it appear that your image is overflowing across the entire page, add gradient to the bottom of the image (for e.g. `#029d7e`), then set the background color as the gradient.

```
background: #029d7e url("http://iforce.co.nz/i/gvudoqvz.ago.png") repeat-x;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/24wkdof5/

If you want your child element to grow with your parent element, you need to mark both elements with `height` attribute (either `100%` or fixed `height`).

Comment: Thanks for the response, this does work for the image but not for the blur effect. @Stefan Dochow has a great response for what im looking for.